# How to set default time to 00:00:00 in kendo Date Time picker

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, datetimepicker

Here is my Kendo datetime picker code

```
@(Html.Kendo().DateTimePicker()
      .Name("start")
      .Value(DateTime.Today)
      .ParseFormats(new string[] { "MM/dd/yyyy" })
)
```

by this am getting 12/22/2014 12:00 AM but i want to diplay as 12/22/2014 00:00:00

how can i set default start date to the current day with the time set to 00:00:00

I tried like this but am not getting to display time as 00:00:00

```
var today = new Date();
    var day = today.getDate();
    var month = today.getMonth();
    var year = today.getFullYear();
    $('#FromDate').data('kendoDateTimePicker').value(month, day, year);

    $('#FromDate').data('kendoDateTimePicker').value(new Date("MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is what you want: http://dojo.telerik.com/UBaQe ?
So in the C# ASP.MVC this code should work:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DateTimePicker()
      .Name("start")
      .Value(DateTime.Today)
      .ParseFormats(new string[] { "MM/dd/yyyy" })
      .Format("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
      .TimeFormat("HH:mm:ss")
)
```